# How to write a lua pattern that is aware of escaped characters?

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I want to write a patterns that takes a string like this `/a/b/c` and extracts `a`, `b`, and `c`. a, b, and c are optional, so `///` is a valid input. Currently I have this: `"^%/(.-)%/(.-)%/(.-)$"`. This works, except if my input is `/</>/b/c`, I get matches: `<`, `>`, `b/c`. Obviously the second `/` should be escaped like this: `/<\\/>/b/c`, however this gives me: `<\`, `>`, `b/c`. Is there a way to write this pattern such that `/<\\/>/b/c` would give me: `<\/>`, `b`, `c`? I know I could change the first `.-` to a `.+` and that would solve this exact issue, but it doesn't solve the larger issue(i.e. what if the escaped slash is in section b).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible to achieve using a single Lua pattern, but you can chain a few of them:

```
local s = "/<\\/>//b\\\\/c"  -- 4 payloads here  (the second one is empty)
for x in s
      :gsub("/", "/\1")       -- make every payload non-empty by prepending string.char(1)
      :gsub("\\(.)", "\2%1")  -- replace magic backslashes with string.char(2)
      :gsub("%f[/\2]/", "\0") -- replace non-escaped slashes with string.char(0)
      :gsub("[\1\2]", "")     -- remove temporary symbols string.char(1) and string.char(2)
      :gmatch"%z(%Z*)"        -- split by string.char(0)
do
   print(x)
end
```

Output:

```
</>

b\
c
```

Or, if you want a single statement instead of a loop:

```
local s = "/<\\/>/b/c"  -- 3 payloads here
local a, b, c = s
      :gsub("/", "/\1")       -- make every payload non-empty by prepending string.char(1)
      :gsub("\\(.)", "\2%1")  -- replace magic backslashes with string.char(2)
      :gsub("%f[/\2]/", "\0") -- replace non-escaped slashes with string.char(0)
      :gsub("[\1\2]", "")     -- remove temporary symbols string.char(1) and string.char(2)
      :match"%z(%Z*)%z(%Z*)%z(%Z*)"  -- split by string.char(0)
```

Comment: You're a wizard. Thank you, this works exactly as I had hoped.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, it's not possible.

Normally, in POSIX ERE a working regex would be:

```
^/(?:[^\\/]|\\.)*/(?:[^\\/]|\\.)*/(?:[^\\/]|\\.)*$
```

...where `(?:[^\\/]|\\.)` means "either not `\` (escaping) and not `/` (delimiter), or an escaped character".

However, Lua patterns don't have `|`. Quantifiers are also not applicable for groups. That said, there is no way to differentiate normal and escaped characters.

The solution is to write your own parser from scratch.